# Expand bootstrap div width with content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs, a `col-md-2` and a `col-md-10`.

**How can I make the `col-md-10` div expand its width with content?**

For example, if I have a really wide table inside the `col-md-10` div, parts of it expand outside the div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this css trick

set it to display: inline-block.

or you can use a diff class with that table and use this custom css

```
.table {
    display: table; /* IE8+ and all other modern browsers */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap has a constant width for `col-md-2` and `col-md-10`,if you want to expand `col-md-10` you need to reduce `col-md-2` width , to do this you should change width property in `col-md-10` class in bootstrap source code

Comment: never ever try to change bootstrap frameworks class, or it will make change in full website, if you really have to change something with that div then please add a different class and make changes there if it is not working please add !important with css proprty.